# Plotting graphs on current barplot in R

Tags: r, matlab, plot, ggplot2

I'm looking for some technique in R similiar to command `hold all` in Matlab.
In Matlab I generate some data:

```
x = normrnd(0,1,1000,1);
[a,b]=hist(x,20);
L=b(2)-b(1);
area=sum(L*a);
frequency=a/area;
bar(b,frequency,1);
hold all; 
range=b(1):0.1:b(20);
f1=normpdf(range,0,1);
f2=normpdf(range,2,2);
plot1=plot(range,f1,'r');
plot2=plot(range,f2,'m');
hold off;
```

I would like to create something similiar in R. I've tried this way:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
h <- hist(x, breaks = 20)
a <- h$counts
b <- h$mids
L <- b[2] - b[1]
area <- sum(L*a)
frequency = a/area
range <- seq(b[1],b[20], by = 0.1)
f1 <- dnorm(range,0,1)
f2 <- dnorm(range,2,2)
barplot(frequency, names.arg = c(b))
```

And I stopped here, since I don't know how to add another graph to current plot. I tried to use ggplot2, but I haven't much experience with that and I failed on creating barplot with this library.
If there is a way to do that with ggplot2, I would like to know it with explanation, since I  want to learn it. I will appreciate solution with traditional plot system aswell.
P.S. I used `barplot(frequency, names.arg = c(b))`, because I read [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Hiebeler-matlabR.pdf), that there is no equivalent in R for Matlab's `bar` function.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes it is better to tell us what you are trying to do, rather than how you are trying to do it.  From the looks of your R code your boxplot is just a scaled histogram and from the other R code and my guesses from the matlab code you want to add reference lines for normal distributions.  If I am correct then you are going about this the long way in R.  The following R code is much simpler:

```
x <- rnorm(1000)
hist(x, prob=TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x,0,1), add=TRUE)
curve(dnorm(x,2,2), add=TRUE)
```

Even better would be to add `col='blue'` or similar to the `curve` calls.  If you really feel the need to choose your own x values then you can replace the calls to curve with:

```
lines(range, dnorm(range, 0, 1) )
lines(range, dnorm(range, 2, 2) )
```

If you really want to learn to add lines to a `barplot` then you should realize that the default locations for bars may not be what you expect.  Look at the `updateusr` function in the TeachingDemos package for R for examples of adding lines to a barplot.

Comment: Thank you, that was very heplful! I was trying to translate code I wrote during lab at my university, but it's good to know that it may be done easier way.